# Django model form choice

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Im using Django 2.1.3 and i'm having some trouble with the "comboboxes".
i have a model with all my fields and them i pass that model fields to a form but when i see my page all the fields that are choicefield don´t show.
what am i doing wrong?

models.py

```
class nconfm(models.Model):
NAT_CHOICES = (
        ('NCI', 'NC Interna'),
        ('NCF', 'NC Fornecedor'),
        ('OS', 'Outra Situação'),
        ('OPM', 'Oportunidade / Melhoria'),
    )
data = models.DateField()
natureza = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=NAT_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
class data(forms.DateInput):
  format_key = 'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS'
  input_type = 'date'
class formnconf(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = nconfm
    fields = ['data','natureza']
    widgets = {
        'data': data(),
    }
```

index.html

```
<form class="site-form" action="" method='POST'>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form}}
</form>
```

views.py

```
from .forms import  formnconf

def nv_conf(request):
form = formnconf
return render(request,'add_nconf.html',{'form' : form})
```

It's fixed it was something on the CSS config

Comment: Show your Views.py function.

Comment: don't forget to adopt the proper naming convention to distinguish classes and objects (i.e. ClassName and object_name)

Comment: @ans2human done

Answer (score -1):

Edited:
Your model:

```
class nconfm(models.Model):
  data = models.DateField()
  natureza = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Your forms.py:

```
class formnconf(forms.ModelForm):
  NAT_CHOICES = (
    ('NCI', 'NC Interna'),
    ('NCF', 'NC Fornecedor'),
    ('OS', 'Outra Situação'),
    ('OPM', 'Oportunidade / Melhoria'),
)
  data = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
  natureza = forms.ChoiceField(choices = NAT_CHOICES, widget= forms.Select())
  class Meta:
    model = nconfm
    fields = ['data','natureza']
```

Comment: No, this is just incorrect. Choices are perfectly valid on a model charfield.

Comment: thank you for correcting my answer. I checked
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/
and learned my lesson.

Comment: i had already try that and it didn't work, i can't understand what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @pksrbx: I checked your view, should it be: 
form = formnconf()
instead of:
form = formnconf 
??

Comment: @CaChach thanks your a lifesaver i saw your video and realized that it could be something related to CSS, i removed all the configs from the CSS and BINGO it works. i was going crazy with this